# SQL Replication groups in Windows failover clusters RRS feed

Tags: sql-server, failover

I have a scenario where there is a Cluster of 2 Windows servers that have SQL Standard. Between those servers is replication, and we need to use replication groups for each database, what is the best scenario and is it better to use DFS replication or SQL replication?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

I believe, DFS replication is meant for files synchronization not for the databases. consider following options as database solutions/features in SQL Server.

**[SQL FCI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/failover-clusters/windows/always-on-failover-cluster-instances-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15#Benefits)**
Since you already have SQL FCI in-place, the databases and data (program files) related to SQL Server are already in shared location which can be accessible to both nodes.

**[Availability Groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/overview-of-always-on-availability-groups-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15)**
Unlike FCI, availability groups hosted by stand-alone SQL instances, each instances called as replica, every replica maintains their own copy of databases and every change in the database replicated all database copies across replicas within a group. you can have 8 replicas, required enterprise license. WSFC required for auto-fail-over purpose.

**[Log Shipping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/log-shipping/about-log-shipping-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15)**
Log shipping works based on scheduled backups, which periodically **backups** the changes on primary server, secondary server **copies** backup files and **restores** regularly as per defined schedule.

**[SQL Replication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/sql-server-replication?view=sql-server-ver15)**
Above options considered as high availability solutions, but replication is something used for copying and distributing the database's objects